# Is compliance level sufficient to run on Java 6?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have set Java Compiler Compliance Level to 1.6 in Eclipse.

A coworker ran some binaries on a machine that runs only Java 6 and execution failed for `Unsupported major.minor version: 51`.

We do not have (yet*) an automated build/CI system: an Ant task builds a JAR from the bare `bin/` directory contents compiled by Eclipse's Auto-build workspace function **and not (yet*!) using javac**. I only run JDK 7 on my machine, I have no trace of JDK 6.

The question is really simple: does setting compliance level affect the output binaries version or does it only block you from using types/syntaxes from the new runtimes?

*`Yet` means we are working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have compiled the code on JDK 7 while your colleague ran it with JAVA 6 binaries. And this is the why he/she got the failure "Unsupported major.minor version: 51".

As stated by Jigar, setting compliance level simply say eclipse to adjust the warning/suggestion according to specified JDK but the code will actually be compiled with the installed JREs/JDK only.

Please install a JDK version 6 and go to preferences->JAVA->Installed JREs -> Add -> select JDK 1.6 from your machine. And clean & build your project.
This will compile your code to be able to run on JRE 6.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I don't have JDK 6? Can I select JDK 7 or do I have to download an install a legacy version?

Comment: Yes, you would need to get JDK 6. OR your colleague may want to get JRE 7.

Comment: The comment above **is** the answer to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

compliance level is for eclipse to understand language features in compiling/warning/suggesting features

You need to also set

Installed JRE to proper version of JDK (note: JDK)

installed JRE is located at

preference -> Java -> Installed JRE

Comment: Could you please expand? Where do I find such an option? Can it be configured for a single project only?